# Организация 'submit' с помощью картинки

Tags: framework, post, php, kohana, веб-программирование

Всем доброго времени суток.

Работаю с "kohana", в которой отправка данных с формы осуществляется с помощью кнопки `"submit"`

```
(<.?=Form::submit('submit', 'Add')?>)
```

С помощью которой в отпраляемый массив вставляется строка `([submit] => Add)`, и затем массив отправляется с успехом обрабатываться в

```
 public function action_add()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
....
        }
    }
```

Я же оформил эту кнопку с помощью графического изображения:

```
<.?=Form::image('submit', 'picture', array('src' => 'media/Img/save.png',
                              'onmouseover' => 'this.src=\'/media/Img/save_click.png\';',
                                'onmouseout' => 'this.src=\'/media/Img/save.png\';',
                                   )
                          )?>
```

Соответственно элемент `([submit] => Add)` в отправляемый массив не попал, и соответственно условие `(if(isset($_POST['submit'])))` не отреагировало.

**Решение**:

Может, стоит поле 'submit' в условии `(if(isset($_POST['submit'])))` заменить на какое-нибудь существующее поле формы, например:

`(if(isset($_POST['**abbreviation**'])))`?

Такое поле на форме есть.

И насколько это является правильным?

Заранее **спасибо**.

Comment: А зачем кнопку анализировать, если Кохана умеет понимать, как пришли данные, достаточно вызвать $this->request->post().

По поводу кнопки:

Что за прошлый век и onmouseover, onmouseout??? Есть css :hover.

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, в контроллере вместо "if(isset($_POST['submit']))" нужно подставить if ($this->request->post()) 
Да, вариан работает, спасибо.
P.S.
Насчет "if(isset($_POST['submit']))", смотрел видеоурок "ШП - Kohana Framework от А до Я".
По поводу кнопки, за совет спасибо.

Comment: Ох уж эти видеоуроки...

Comment: А нсчет кнопки, я посмотрел, т.к. вы написали не получится, я ее с помощью "http://cooltext.com/Logo-Design-Hot-Rod-Button" делал

Comment: Я тоже работаю с этим фреймворком и не могу понять, зачем обычную кнопочку генерить через php?

Comment: Как вариант
    <input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="add" style="display:none">
    <img src="..." onclick="document.getElementById('add').click()">

Comment: Просто кнопки красивые получаются, та и работал я с этими кнопками 
уже

Comment: А в чем проблема сделать `<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">` и внутрь запихнуть картинку?

Comment: @Konstantin78, я не поленился

    <?php
    
    $contents = array();
    foreach ($images as $image) {
         $contents[] = HTML::image($image);
    }
    echo Form::button('submit', implode('', $contents), array('type' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Add'));